# How to package executable JAR file into EXE

Tags: java, deployment, exe, wrapper, executable

I would like to deploy my final build as an EXE with an application Icon.

What is the best way to do this? What is the common practice?

Comment: For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

Answer (score 7):

Launch4j is a cross-platform tool for wrapping Java applications distributed as jars in lightweight Windows native executables. The executable can be configured to search for a certain JRE version or use a bundled one, and it's possible to set runtime options, like the initial/max heap size. The wrapper also provides better user experience through an application icon, a native pre-JRE splash screen, a custom process name, and a Java download page in case the appropriate JRE cannot be found.

http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I use jar2exe on Windows. Is a simple wizard done in java where you are asked to input your jar the icon of the exe and a few more information. Here is the link [jar2exe](http://www.jar2exe.com/)

Comment: Is there any open source version available?