# What is the best way to export a file from Eclipse so that it can be run on multiple Operating Systems?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I want to be able to export a file from Eclipse that can be run on Windows/Linux/Mac. Just wondering if there is any simple/elegant way to do this. I know it is possible to something like this with Processing (processing.org) which leads me to think that there might be a similar plugin for Eclipse.

Also (maybe i should create a new question for this but..), I am also wondering if build tools such as Maven and Ant can help with this problem?

Sorry - bit of a noob.

Thanks

Comment: Best way to use your program in multiple OSs ? Make an executable jar file for it. Google "how to make a jar file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an executable jar-file directly from Eclipse,

1. Right click project
2. "Export"
3. "Java" > "Runnable JAR file"
4. Choose the class with your main method in the "Launch configuration" dropdown
5. Choose export destination and finish

This should create a jar-File that can be ran from any machine with a suitable JRE installation.

For your second question: You've got that right, both maven and ant are tools that (among other things) help you package your application into something you can deploy to your users or web servers.

Comment: and can maven/ant be used to create a more standardized installer rather than just downloading a jar file? I know in Ubuntu jar files normally open in the archive manager by default and I assume that there might be some similar issues with WIN/MAC. I'd love to be able to just export the project and make it as easily accessible to users as possible ...

Comment: I'm a web application developer so I don't have any experience with that, sorry :( **EDIT**: I'm not sure about maven/ant integration, but [here's a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17176900/how-to-package-executable-jar-file-into-exe) with an answer about converting jar files to exe files

Comment: Great stuff. That Jar2Exe program mentioned in the thread looks like it might be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in Java, you can just generate a .jar file containing the classes needed by your application, and bundle it with any other .jar files it depends upon.

This does require that the other system have a Java environment installed which is recent enough to support the language features your program is using, and that that the user has enough of a clue to make sure the jarfiles are on the classpath and to start your main class appropriately.

If you aren't willing to count on that much cluefulness, there are installer-builders which will bundle a set of jarfiles with a copy of the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) and an appropriate set of scripts to launch the app in the common environments. I haven't used them so I can't recommend, and specific tool recommendations are usually out of scope for Stack Overflow anyway.